# How to reset state of initial ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, camera, segue

I've 2 ViewController's: `VC1` and `VC2`. In `VC1` i've :

```
 @IBAction func cliclOnBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
          CameraController.takePicture()

    }
...



func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

        print("didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo", picker.sourceType)
        let _image = (info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage)
        ImageView.image = _image
        Images.append(_image)
}
```

In `VC2` i'm passing array of `_image`, but when i try to back on `VC1`, photos from camera adding by clicking again. How to reset data? How to make reset of an array of photo, when back button pressed ?

Comment: use protocol for that

Comment: @ pradeepchauhan_pc I'm a little confused by this. Сould you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement `viewWillAppear` in VC1, and then remove all elements of the image Array. This way, when you tap back on VC2, the VC1 will have it's image Array empty.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    Images.removeAll()
}
```

Btw, consider renaming your instance variables, lowercasing the initial character, it's a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Use protocol with delegate for sending data to back 
You can update UI or code in delegate function

```
import UIKit

protocol DestinationViewControllerDelegate {
     func updateData(text:String); // you can use Array, Dictonary, Modal as  per your requirment
}

class DestinationViewController: UIViewController {
     var delegate:FullCalendarViewDelegate! = nil

     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
     }

     @IBAction func doneButton(sender: AnyObject) {
         delegate?.updateData("Got new data")
         self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
     }
}
```

// Sender View Controller

```
class SenderViewController: UIViewController, DestinationViewControllerDelegate {

     @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
     }

     @IBAction func NextButton(sender: AnyObject) {
         let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
         let dash:DestinationViewControllerDelegate =    storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DestinationViewControllerDelegate") as! DestinationViewControllerDelegate
         dash.delegate = self
         self.navigationController?.pushViewController(dash, animated: true)
     }

     func updateData(text:String) {
         titleLabel.text = text
     }
}
```